# определение функции союза

Tags: союзы

Почему грамматически возможно выражение "пришел, но поздно", ведь в данном случае перед нами не однородные члены предложения, а сказуемое и обстоятельство?

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Пришел, но поздно.*

**1. В неполном предложении**

Значение фразы определяется по контексту, а домыслить ее можно по-разному:

(1) Он всё-таки пришел, но пришел поздно. Союз НО соединяет однородные сказуемые.

(2) Он пришел, но было уже поздно. Сложное предложение. Например: Берегись! Петрович отдергивает руку, но поздно – крышка срывается с чайника.

**2.  В обычном предложении**

Существует два вида союзов НО: **противительный и  присоединительный**. В простом предложении противительный союз действительно относится **к однородным членам,** а присоединительный  может использоваться для различных конструкций, например:

(1) **Противительный союз НО**, разделение запятой: *Солнечный, но холодный день* близился к концу.

(2) **Присоединительный союз НО**, выделение  запятыми: *Посидели, но больше для приличия, ещё несколько минут.*

Answer (score 2):

> Почему грамматически возможно выражение "пришел, но поздно", ведь в
> данном случае перед нами не однородные члены предложения

Оно так, но союз НО (в значении "однако") по своему функционалу вовсе не требует однородности соединяемых им членов.

Впрочем, ваш пример может объясняться  проще, тут напрашивается опушенное сказуемое, известное из первой части высказывания, - и таким образом грамматическая однородность  соблюдается.
***Он пришел, но [пришел] поздно.***